# Type Mayan numerals?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, characters

I would like to know 3 things:

1. Are Mayan numerals included in the latest version of Unicode?
2. Is it possible to type Mayan numerals on a computer w/o Unicode?
3. If #2 is possible, how would I do it?

I've looked this up on the internet myself and I just cannot find out how, no doubt because it's likely such a rarely asked question, but still, I'm curious. I do know how to write Mayan numerals to a very good extent and I would like to know if it's possible to incorporate that in certain web applications I type on at times.

Please refer to another site if this is on the wrong one; I'm not sure if I picked the right SA site for this topic.

Answer (score 3):

Unicode 11.0.0, released June 5, 2018 includes Mayan numerals in block `U+1D2E0 - U+1D2F3`. [Mayan Numerals](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D2E0.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

> (1) Are Mayan numerals included in the latest version of Unicode?

No, not yet. "Maya hieroglyphs" are mentioned in the [Unicode Roadmap for Supplementary Multilingual Plane](http://www.unicode.org/roadmaps/smp/), though.

AFAIK, most such proposals to Unicode are done by the [Script Encoding Initiative](http://www.linguistics.berkeley.edu/sei/); perhaps contact them.

> (2) Is it possible to type Mayan numerals on a computer w/o Unicode?

As text, generally no – there isn't any widely used character set that supports them; certainly not the common ISO-8859 or similar ones. [TRON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRON_(encoding)) might work, but I do not know any systems that support it.

Comment: Ah, I think I will look into those links you posted. Thanks so much. :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes:https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D2E0.pdf
2. It probably depends on what other system you use.  If you use an encoding system which includes mayan numerals then yes.
3. It depends on the non-unicode format you use.

Answer (score 1):

Since Mayan numerals are not included yet in Unicode, as @grawity explains, you would need to resort to [Private Use](http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html) codepoints. This means that the data can be processed meaningfully only by programs that adhere to a specific “private” agreement. In an application that is shipped with a font of its own, this may be feasible. E.g., the [Maya font](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/) assigns Mayan numerals to Private Use codepoints U+F7F7...U+F847. If you create your own font, you can use any Private Use codepoints (provided that they do not conflict with possible other uses for Private Use in your application).

Although Private Use codepoints have no characters assigned to them in the Unicode Standard, they can be processed like character. However, they have no special character properties (like being alphabetic or numeric, having a numeric value, etc.), so all processing must be handled at a low level in the application. But you can e.g. create a keyboard layout or a virtual keyboard that lets the user type them, just like you can for normal allocared characters,

Comment: Hmm... Interesting. That's quite a fascinating idea, although I'm not quite that experienced in encoding yet so perhaps I leave it in the back of my head for a distant rainy day. Haha. Thanks!